# Python Cython magic functions not working

Tags: python, cython, jupyter, spyder

I have 3 questions about my Python code (I am fairly new to it)
I am trying to build a Cython code from my working Python code to get it working faster (hopefully). I tried doing it the way of making a setup.py file and I managed to make it until I ran the file I made to run it with (saved as run_practice.py):

```
 import pyximport; pyximport.install()
 import practice.pyx
```

in terminal and got an error in terminal that it couldn't find the ‘3d’ projection type, as my code graphs values in a 3d plot.

I searched a lot to fix this problem but there was literally nothing about it. Part A of my question is how I could fix this.

So I came across the cythonmagic method. I read that cythonmagic is now part of the Cython package and adjusted my code accordingly. I have the current version of Anaconda and also the current version of Jupyter and pretty much everything else Anaconda offers. I copied and pasted my working Python code into a Jupyter notebook and got it run, but here are the problems:
I initiated the code with

```
%load_ext Cython
%%cython
```

then pasted my code after. At the end I get an error that says "  File "", line 6
    %%cython
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

and this makes no sense because it didn’t have any trouble loading the Cython extension, and when I typed just ‘%cython’ in the second line it SUGGESTED me to type ‘%%cython’, and it appeared the magic function was readable from the error message '(ERROR:root:Line magic function `%cython` not found (But cell magic `%%cython` exists, did you mean that instead?))'
, and got this syntax error. Also I mentioned earlier that I have a 3d plot that is generated from my code, and this doesn’t show up anywhere when I run it in the Jupyter notebook, but works fine in the Spyder environment.
Those two questions are part B of my questions.

Here is my total code. The nested for loops are obviously the crutch of the code. Just a little basis…the ‘Fraction’ variable tells to what degree of accuracy the ‘theta’ and ‘beta’ are iterated in the for loops. At Fraction = 1, run time is 0.1499929428100586 seconds, but at Fraction = .1, the run time is about 13 seconds (the smaller ‘Fraction’, the higher degree of accuracy). I need the code to run efficiently to at least 10 decimal places (Fraction = .0000000001 or something) and this would completely freeze up my computer (even at Fraction = 0.005 my computer freezes up!). Any help on optimizing this would help tremendously!! Thanks so much!

Also don’t bother about the Correction factor terms being either a linespace array or not…currently working around appending a 3d array from a 3rd variable iterating in a for loop.

```
"""
Created on Tue Nov 22 23:13:40 2016
@author: Eric Holmes
"""
# Scattering formulas
# Eric Holmes
# Constants
import math
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pvlib as pv
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import time
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
h = 6.62607004e-34 # Plank Constant m^2*kg/s
c = 299792458 # Speed of light m/s
m = 9.10938356e-31 # Mass kg
r = 2.8179403267e-15
pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093844609550582231725359408128481117450284102701938521105559644622948954930381964428810975665933446128475648233786783165271201909145648566923460348610454326648213393607260249141273
try:
    InitialElectronVelocity = float(input("Enter Initial Electron Velocity: "))
except ValueError:
    InitialElectronVelocity = 2e8
try:
    InitialPhotonWavelength = float(input("Enter Initial Photon Wavelength: "))
except ValueError:
    InitialPhotonWavelength = 2.426310236092620e-12
try:
    MinALPHAAngleEvaluated = float(input("Enter Min ALPHA Angle Evaluated: ")) 
except ValueError:
    MinALPHAAngleEvaluated = 90
try:
    MaxALPHAAngleEvaluated = float(input("Enter Max ALPHA Angle Evaluated: ")) 
except ValueError:
    MaxALPHAAngleEvaluated = 90
try:
    Fraction = float(input("Enter Fraction: ")) 
except ValueError:
    Fraction = 1
try:
    THETABETAMINANGLEEVALUATED = float(input("Enter THETA/BETA MIN ANGLE EVALUATED: "))
except ValueError:
    THETABETAMINANGLEEVALUATED = 0
try:
    THETABETAMAXANGLEEVALUATED = float(input("Enter THETA/BETA MAX ANGLE EVALUATED: "))
except ValueError:
    THETABETAMAXANGLEEVALUATED = 90
start = time.time()
gamma = 1/(math.sqrt(1-((InitialElectronVelocity**2)/(c**2))))       
Elambda1 = ((h*c)/InitialPhotonWavelength)                        
Eelectron1 = (gamma*m*(c**2))                                        
SCALEDALPHAMinAngle = MinALPHAAngleEvaluated/Fraction                       
SCALEDALPHAMaxAngle = MaxALPHAAngleEvaluated/Fraction                       
JJ = ((SCALEDALPHAMaxAngle - SCALEDALPHAMinAngle)/Fraction)
QQ = (JJ + (1/Fraction))*Fraction                           
CORRECTIONFACTOR1 = ((SCALEDALPHAMinAngle) - (1))                         
if SCALEDALPHAMinAngle == SCALEDALPHAMaxAngle:
    CORRECTIONFACTOR2 = np.linspace(1,1,1)                                                
else:
    CORRECTIONFACTOR2 = np.linspace(SCALEDALPHAMinAngle,SCALEDALPHAMaxAngle,QQ)   
SCALEDTHETABETAMinAngle = THETABETAMINANGLEEVALUATED/Fraction                  
SCALEDTHETABETAMaxAngle = THETABETAMAXANGLEEVALUATED/Fraction                   
JJJ = ((SCALEDTHETABETAMaxAngle - SCALEDTHETABETAMinAngle)/Fraction) 
QQQ = (JJJ + (1/Fraction))*Fraction                        
CORRECTIONFACTOR3 = ((SCALEDTHETABETAMinAngle) - 1)                    
if SCALEDTHETABETAMinAngle == SCALEDTHETABETAMaxAngle:
    CORRECTIONFACTOR4 = np.linspace(1,1,1)
else:                                        
    CORRECTIONFACTOR4 = np.linspace(SCALEDTHETABETAMinAngle,SCALEDTHETABETAMaxAngle,QQQ)
length1 = np.shape(CORRECTIONFACTOR4)
length2 = np.shape(CORRECTIONFACTOR2)
int1 = length1[0] 
int2 = length2[0]
int3 = int1 + 1
int4 = int2 + 1
alpha = 1
matrix1 = []
for theta in range(1,int3):
    i = theta - 1
    matrix1.append([])
    for beta in range(1,int3):
        Elambda2 = ((h*c*(((InitialElectronVelocity*pv.tools.cosd((alpha + CORRECTIONFACTOR1)*Fraction))-c)))/((((h/(m*gamma)))*(pv.tools.cosd((theta + CORRECTIONFACTOR3)*Fraction)-1))-(InitialPhotonWavelength*(c-(InitialElectronVelocity*pv.tools.cosd((beta + CORRECTIONFACTOR3)*Fraction))))))
        DifferentialCrossSection = (((pi*(r**2))/2)*((m**2)/(Elambda1*(Eelectron1**2)))*((((m**4)/(4*(Elambda1**2)*(Eelectron1**2))) * (((Elambda2/(Eelectron1-Elambda2)))**2)) - (((m**2)/(Elambda1*Eelectron1))*((Elambda2/(Eelectron1-Elambda2)))) + ((Eelectron1 - Elambda2)/(Eelectron1)) + ((Eelectron1/(Eelectron1-Elambda2)))))          
        matrix1[i].append(DifferentialCrossSection)     
Y = np.linspace(SCALEDTHETABETAMinAngle,SCALEDTHETABETAMaxAngle,QQQ) 
Z = np.reshape(Y,(int1,1))                 
theta = np.tile(Z,(1,int1))
beta  = np.tile(Y,(int1,1)) 
ax.plot_wireframe((theta*Fraction),(beta*Fraction),matrix1)
matrix2 = np.reshape(matrix1,(1,(int1*int1)))
minimum = np.amin(matrix2)
maximum = np.amax(matrix2)
ax.auto_scale_xyz([THETABETAMINANGLEEVALUATED, THETABETAMAXANGLEEVALUATED], [THETABETAMINANGLEEVALUATED, THETABETAMAXANGLEEVALUATED], [minimum, maximum])   
end = time.time()
print("Code Run Time =",(end - start),"seconds")
```

Comment: There is really to much here. When asking a question, it is important to get to the heart of the question as quickly as reasonable.

Comment: Sorry I know theres a lot of material…I tried to make the issues as clear as possible

Comment: I don't just mean the code, I also mean your question body. You should be able to state your question in a single paragraph. Anything which comes after that should simply be the research you've done. For example, paragaphs 6 & 7 of your question are unnecessary, and just add length to the question.

Comment: cell magics (`%%cython`) must be the first line of the cell.  Put the `%load_ext Cython` line in its own cell, then start the next cell (containing your Cython code) with `%%cython`.